# CPIO ulimit reached error

Tags: unix, cpio

I have been googling this without much luck.  I hope someone can help here.

We have a customer running SCO Unixware 7 machine.  This machine does a daily backup to tape.  These have stopped running.  It goes through and gets into the /home directory and produces the following error

```
UX:cpio: HALT: ulimit reached for output file.
```

This runs out of the root crontab and the ulimit settings for root is this

```
# ulimit -a
time(seconds) unlimited
file(blocks) unlimited
data(kbytes) unlimited
stack(kbytes) 16384
coredump(blocks) 32768
nofiles(descriptors) 256
memory(kbytes) unlimited
```

I am unsure what all of the sudden has caused this to stop working.  What can I do to help alleviate this issue?

Current Crontab entry

```
0 23 * * 1-6 /tech/mn/autobackup.sh
```

Suggested Crontab entry

```
0 23 * * 1-6 ulimit -f unlimited; sh /tech/mn/autobackup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The ulimits for a root login are not necessarily the same as the ulimits in the cron-spawned cpio. Run `ulimit -Sa` and `ulimit -Ha` from the root crontab to find out what the limits inherited by cron jobs are.

Some Unixes have a convenient/exasperating feature where they will configurably apply limits to sessions on session creation, for example in `/etc/login.conf`.

My approach would be to insert `ulimit -f unlimited;` on the crontab line before the real command.

Comment: I added the current and the suggested crontab to the OP.  Is that how you where recommending I try it?

Comment: Yes, though the extra `sh` after the `;` is unnecessary.

Comment: ok i will give it a try and see what happens

Comment: So I tried adding that to cron.  the backup still failed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, the error message clearly refers to the file ulimit. Either it's wrong, or the ulimit is being set inside the `autobackup.sh` script somewhere.